# Query string with dynamic content

Tags: php, hyperlink, query-string

If I have this index:

```
if (isset($_GET['se'])) {
    $se= $_GET['se'];

    if (file_exists("{$se}.php")){
        require("{$se}.php");
    }
    else {
        require("page_error.php");
    }
}
else {
    require("page_error.php");
}
```

A link like the following doesn't work:

```
$pwrurl = "http://example.com/login/?se=change_password?usermail=".$email."&usercode=".$linkHash;
```

Only something like: `http://example.com/login/?se=change_password` will be accepted.

Can this be solved?

Comment: Try using a `&` as separator. You have two `?` which is incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean 'dynamic' (not dinamic)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware!

Letting the user decide which file to include without any validation will introduce a vulnerability to your server.  They could point your script to any sensitive file.

You should limit the possibilities of what can be included, like this:

```
$allowed_files = array(
    "page_error",
    "some_section",
    "some_other_section",
    "change_password"
    );

$se = empty($_GET['se']) ? "page_error" : $_GET['se'] ; // "page_error" by default.

if (in_array($se, $allowed_files)){
    require("{$se}.php");
} else {
    require("page_error.php");
}
```

This way they can only read the files you put in the array.

Edit:  Also, just like everyone else said, you should separate different param=argument pairs in the URL with & instead of ?.  The ? is used to separate the page name from the argument list.

```
http://example.com/login/?se=change_password&usermail=...
```

Comment: Use that filter but don't rely on that only, because it will not protect you from the vulnerability I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You have two `?` in the URL. Multiple parameters have to be separated with `&`.

Your use of `require` is *very dangerous*. Read up on security. Validate any parameter before passing it to such a dangerous function, or your site will be hacked in no time.

Answer (score 2):

The link is wrong, it should be '&' instead of '?' after change_password.

```
$pwrurl = "http://example.com/login/?se=change_password&usermail=".$email."&usercode=".$linkHash;
```